# looping through Json object with multiple arrays Python3

Tags: python, arrays, json, ocr

I have an OCR data stored in a JSON object and it looks like this:

```
{
  "language": "ar",
  "textAngle": 0,
  "orientation": "Right",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "191,26,283,265",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "191,26,283,22",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "191,28,95,20",
              "text": "KINGDOM",
              "confidence": 861
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "292,27,26,18",
              "text": "OF",
              "confidence": 826
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "323,26,64,19",
              "text": "SAUDI",
              "confidence": 840
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "393,26,81,18",
              "text": "ARABIA",
              "confidence": 765
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "215,58,237,20",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "215,59,98,19",
              "text": "MINISTRY",
              "confidence": 812
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "318,58,28,18",
              "text": "OF",
              "confidence": 996
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "353,58,99,18",
              "text": "INTERIOR",
              "confidence": 713
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "243,258,137,33",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "243,258,137,33",
              "text": "االل",
              "confidence": 999
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "523,29,230,57",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "545,29,186,30",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "545,29,81,30",
              "text": "سياقة",
              "confidence": 999
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "632,30,99,29",
              "text": "رخصة",
              "confidence": 999
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "523,70,230,16",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "523,70,107,16",
              "text": "DRIVING",
              "confidence": 679
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "642,70,111,16",
              "text": "LICENSE",
              "confidence": 781
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
.
.
.
.
}
```

I want to write each text key value inside word array which is inside lines array.
my code is like this:

```
with open('data3.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for each in azure_json['regions']:
            print(each['lines'][0]['words'][0]['text'])
```

but it gives me only the first text key value in each FIRST words array that inside line array, i.e. the output of this code is look like this:

```
KINGDOM
سياقة
```

So it gives me only the first text in the two lines.
I want to print out all the text key values inside each word array for each line.

Please help.

Comment: it would be better if you can provide sample outputs

Comment: Hint: How are you making it get one of those key values *for each region*? Now,  use the same technique to get each `text` key for a given one of the `words`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over everything instead of indexing on the first item.

```
for region in azure_json["regions"]:
    for line in region["lines"]:
        for word in line["words"]:
            print(word["text"])
```

Output will be something like:

```
KINGDOM
OF
SAUDI
ARABIA
MINISTRY
OF
INTERIOR
االل
سياقة
رخصة
DRIVING
LICENSE
```

If you want to write to the file instead of printing to standard output, just use the `write` method -- your example code for some reason opens an output file but then does not write to it.  Note that you will have to supply the newline (`"\n"`) explicitly:

```
with open('data3.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for region in azure_json["regions"]:
        for line in region["lines"]:
            for word in line["words"]:
                f.write(word["text"] + "\n")
```

Comment: thanks, it works!! actually I've tried this idea but it gave me an error maybe something with the syntax.

Comment: Oh, and before anybody suggests `f.write("".join(word["text"] + "\n" for region in azure_json["regions"] for line in region["lines"] for word in line["words"]))` -- there is a time and place for that sort of one-liner. This is not one of them... :-)

Comment: @Nour_em maybe you forgot the colons or didn't indent it correctly? Anyway hopefully you can compare your attempt with the working version and see what went wrong.